# Same homorphism group fundamental

Tags: homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, continuous-homomorphisms

Prove that two continuous mappings φ, ψ:X→Y, with φ(x0)=ψ(x0) for some point x0∈X, induce the same homomorphism from π(X,x0) to π(Y,φ(x0)) if φ and ψ are homotopic relative to x0.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to think about that should lead you to an answer:

1. What is an element of a fundamental group?
2. Given a continuous function $f:X\to Y$, how does the induced homomorphism $\pi_1(X,x_0)\to \pi_1(Y,f(x_0))$ work?
3. Given two loops in $Y$ based at $\psi(x_0)$, what does it mean that the corresponding elements in $\pi_1(Y, \psi(x_0))$ are equal?
4. What was the relation between $\psi$ and $\varphi$ again? What does that mean, specifically?

Comment: I understood all questions but the last no. What means the relation ? I want to proove that [φof ]=[ψof] if f€π1(X,x0) .  And I know that φ and ψ are homotopic relative to x0. I NEED SOMETHING MORE?

Comment: What does "$\psi$ and $\varphi$ are homotopic relative to $x_0$" mean?

Comment: My problem is I dont know that means.

Comment: Then this problem is unsolvable until you find out. Does your book have the definition? It should, most likely before it defines the fundamental group.

Comment: I find it now. I think I have to define a new homotopia . Its true?

Comment: @PaulaZasCastro You are told that there is a homotopy $H$ between $\varphi$ and $\phi$. What you should do is to use that to construct a homotopy betwen $\varphi\circ f$ and $\psi\circ f$. This shows that $[\varphi\circ f] = [\psi\circ f]$ as elements of $\pi_1(Y, \psi(x_0))$.